# stacked bar charts on polar graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe that looks like this (this is a sample of a larger dataframe):

```
  dvmph variable    value
1      1       X0    100.0
2      3       X0   2486.6
3      5       X0 100519.3
4      7       X0 471515.0
5      1       X1 973180.2
6      3       X1 758789.6
7      5       X1 500884.34
8      7       X1 441252.43
9      9       X1 228094.07
10     1       X2 358144.00
11     3       X2 173614.35
12     5       X2  73395.79
13     7       X2  79245.32
14     9       X2  59789.64
15     1       X3  35539.05
16     3       X3  23196.88
17     5       X3  15686.76
18     7       X3  10589.20
19     9       X3  11124.05
20     1       X4   5221.25
21     3       X4   5630.40
22     5       X4   4045.34
23     7       X4  13108.06
24     9       X4    302.23
```

I want to get a stacked bar chart something like this (the axes will be different, since the above data is just a sample):

[image]

Here is my current code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(variable, dvmph, fill=value)) + geom_bar(stat='identity', position='stack')
```

I don't care about the color difference, but the y-axis is very distorted, and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong:

[image]

The end goal for this data is to plot all the bars on a polar axis, with dvmph as r and variable as theta (apologies for the terrible drawing, I hope this makes sense):

[image]

My two questions are:

1. Why is my y-axis so distorted?
2. Is there an easy way to plot these bars on a polar plot?

Answer (score 2):

From you drawing, I believe you are passing the wrong values to `aes()` -- that is, for your stacked bar example, I believe you want this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = factor(dvmph))) +
  geom_col()
```

[image: Plot]

Then you can add `coord_polar()` to obtain the following:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = factor(dvmph))) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_polar()
```

[image: Plot Polar]

If you dislike the scientific notation, you could always add: `+ scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma_format())`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I see what you're getting at, but the y-value should be based on "dvmph", not "value". "dvmph" should represent r in the polar plot-- which you did in your example (sort of)-- but the fill value should be based on "value". I edited my example of the polar plot to show what I mean.

Comment: Try: `ggplot(df, aes(x = variable, y = factor(dvmph), fill = value)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_polar()` or perhaps explain what you are doing a bit more and illustrate the question(s) you are trying to answer/understand with this graphic. I have a feeling that a polar graph may not be the most appropriate visualization.

Comment: Apologies-- I tried to add some more illustrations on the polar graphic. The reason I chose a polar graph is because the it's showing the frequency of different car crash angles (dvmph is speed at crash, and each variable is a different degree of crash (270 = head-on, 180 = left-side, etc., where the car is in the middle). Does that make more sense? Not sure what else I should add. I tried your suggestion but it looks even stranger: http://imgur.com/YHtKGu7.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You have two predictor variables, `variable` and `dvmph`, and one response variable `value` which is a frequency. So, your approach to plot both predictor variables in an x-y-plot, or as polar plot with angle and radius, resp., and show the response variable color-coded is sensible. Unfortunately, you have chosen the wrong geometry.

Please, try `geom_tile()` instead of `geom_bar()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DT, aes(variable, factor(dvmph), fill=value)) + geom_tile()
```

[image]

or in polar coordinates:

```
ggplot(DT, aes(variable, factor(dvmph), fill=value)) + geom_tile() +
  coord_polar() + theme_linedraw()
```

[image]